# Unimodality of chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory

The chromatic polynomial of a graph $G=(V,E)$ on $n$ vertices is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ik^i$.
The unimodal conjecture (unproven) states that the absolute values of the coefficients are unimodal,
i.e. that for some $k$ $|a_1|\leq|a_2|\leq\ldots|a_k|\geq|a_{k+1}|\ldots\geq|a_n|$.

Now this chromatic polynomial can also be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i(k)_i$ where
$(k)_i$ is the falling factorial $k(k-1)\ldots(k-i+1)$.
In this representation $b_i$ is the number of ways that $V$ can be partitioned into $i$ independent sets
(so the $b_i$ are all non-negative).

I am curious to know whether this sequence $b_i$ is unimodal. It seems much more obvious than
the unimodality of the $|a_i|$, but until now I have been unable to prove it. Can anybody help?

Comment: The unimodal conjecture was reportedly proved http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2012-25-03/S0894-0347-2012-00731-0/

Comment: @Rebecca: thanks, I was not aware of that proof.
Anyway I hope/expect that the (easier?) question I am asking has an elementary proof.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones if I am not mistaken, the paper directly proves the log-concavity of the chromatic polynomial right? How does that boil down to unimodality? Could you elaborate

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I don't get the internal zeros statement of the paper-any hints why it should work?